# How can I delete a row in the view only if the AJAX call & db deletion was successful?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table where each row has a button for deletion. Actually I delete the row everytime without checking if the ajax call was successfull. How can I achieve that, so that the row will only be deleted if the ajax call was ok.

Here is my clickhandler on each row

```
$("body").on('click', ".ui-icon-trash" ,function(){

    var $closestTr = $(this).closest('tr');  // This will give the closest tr
                            // If the class element is the child of tr          
    deleteRowFromDB(oTable, closestTr);
    $closestTr.remove() ;  // Will delete that
 });
```

And here my ajax call

```
function deleteRowFromDB(oTable, sendallproperty){

        var deleteEntryRoute = #{jsRoute @Application.deleteConfigurationEntry() /}
        console.log("route is: " + deleteEntryRoute.url)
        $.ajax({
           url: deleteEntryRoute.url({id: sendallproperty}),
           type: deleteEntryRoute.method,
           data: 'id=' + sendallproperty
        });
```

Comment: Put your code for deleting a row in the ajax call's success handler.

Comment: can you show me in an example code?

Comment: I would, but there are a few problems. Your deleteRowFromDB function has parameters oTable and sendallproperty, which appears to be used as a string. You are passing it two undefined variables when you invoke it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call it in the **success callback** function of your Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
         url: deleteEntryRoute.url({id: sendallproperty}),
         type: deleteEntryRoute.method,
         data: 'id=' + sendallproperty.
         success : function() {
             // Your code here
        }
     });
```

**EDIT**

```
$("body").on('click', ".ui-icon-trash" ,function(){

    var $closestTr = $(this).closest('tr');     
    deleteRowFromDB(oTable, $closestTr);
});

function deleteRowFromDB(oTable, sendallproperty){

   var deleteEntryRoute = #{jsRoute @Application.deleteConfigurationEntry() /}
   console.log("route is: " + deleteEntryRoute.url)
   $.ajax({
           url: deleteEntryRoute.url({id: sendallproperty}),
           type: deleteEntryRoute.method,
           data: 'id=' + sendallproperty,
           success : function() {
             sendallProperty.remove();
           }
   });
};
```

Also `{id: sendallproperty}`   is a jQuery Object ..

If you want to pass the id ... You need to do this

```
{id: sendallproperty.attr('id')}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but how do I know there which table row should be deleted?

Comment: When are you sending the Ajax request ??

Comment: It will be called when a delete icon on row has been pressed. Then if the entry has been deleted successfully on the server, the corresponding row should be deleted

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on('click', ".ui-icon-trash" ,function(){

    var $closestTr = $(this).closest('tr');  // This will give the closest tr
                        // If the class element is the child of tr          
    if(true === deleteRowFromDB(oTable, closestTr)){
        //if true returned from the success in the ajax function, then we remove
        $closestTr.remove() ;  // Will delete that
    }

 });



function deleteRowFromDB(oTable, sendallproperty){

    var deleteEntryRoute = #{jsRoute @Application.deleteConfigurationEntry() /}
    console.log("route is: " + deleteEntryRoute.url)
    $.ajax({
       url: deleteEntryRoute.url({id: sendallproperty}),
       type: deleteEntryRoute.method,
       data: 'id=' + sendallproperty,
       success:function(data){
           return true;
       },
       error:function(){
           return false;
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: You already make use of the success event, why not do it all there?

Comment: @Babak Naffas is there any particular reason why it shouldn't be done this way?